# java Scanner object throws a NoSuchElement exception when trying to read an InputStream object returned from an Http request

Tags: java, android

Scanner class provides a constructor that takes an InputStream as a parameter

So i created an HttpResponse object and use the getEntity() method of this class to get the HttpEntity and then called the getContent() on the entity to get an InputStream object. So i tried to use Scanner to read the returned InputStream object but it fails. 
I encountered this problem when trying to connect to a database in my android app using an HttpGet request, i have a php script hosted locally which executes some queries to mySQL database and echoes the results

P.S
using the statement below gives me the results fetched from the database without any problem

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

but i was just curious as to why the Scanner wouldn't work, i wanna be a great developer, so whenever i encounter such a problem i try to understand why the problem occurred to begin with.

here is my code snippet of the AsyncTask

```
package com.example.helloworld;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.URI;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class SignIn extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

private TextView roleField;
private Context context;
private int byGetOrPost= 0;


public SignIn(Context context,TextView roleField,int flag)
{

    this.context=context;
    this.roleField = roleField;
    byGetOrPost = flag;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    if(byGetOrPost == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            String username = params[0];
            String password=params[1];
            String link = "http://10.0.2.2/myandroidapp/create.php?username="+username+"&password="+password;
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent());
            //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line ="";

            while((line=in.nextLine())!=null)
            {
                sb.append(line);

            }

            in.close();
            return sb.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    else

    {
        try
        {
            return  null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{

    this.roleField.setText(result);
}


}
```

when i use the Scanner object, a NoSuchElement exception is thrown. here is the stack trace

```
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕  java.util.NoSuchElementException
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1363)
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at com.example.helloworld.SignIn.doInBackground(SignIn.java:54)
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at com.example.helloworld.SignIn.doInBackground(SignIn.java:20)
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-23 10:54:05.460    2188-2207/com.example.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

when i get rid of the Scanner and use the BufferedReader instead,it works. Ofcourse in the while loop i changed "in.nextLine()" to "in.readLine()" when i use the BufferedReader to read the content. It returns the correct results fetched from the database

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

my question is why does

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

work but

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

doesn't work?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the failing code as well.

Comment: 'It fails' is not a problem description.

Comment: Not sufficiently. There is still no code, and no stack trace. There is no such thing as a 'null object exception', but there is a `NullPointerException`. However it is not 'returned' but thrown. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: I added the code snippets, stack trace and elaborated the problem further. thank you for your feedback. Am new on StackExchange, so such feedback helps me learn how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A BufferedReader and a Scanner don't work the same way.

`BufferedReader.readLine()` returns the next line, or null if there is no next line.

`Scanner.nextLine()` returns the next line, or throws an exception if there is none. You're supposed to check if there is a next line, before  calling `nextLine()`, by calling `hasNextLine()`.

This is documented. Read the javadoc.

Comment: wow !! thank you sir, this actually worked. The reason i ignored using hasNextLine() is because i thought using nextLine() will return null if there is no next line but it actually throws an exception like you said. My bad cause i don't read the javadoc, i usually find it very verbose. I'll start referring to the javadoc from now on whenever i encounter a problem. Thank you again

Comment: As one once said: "One week of trials and errors can save you up to half an hour of reading the documentation."